# Intercept XHR Response in CefSharp WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

**Goal:**
Read all XHR responses (application/json) that occur on the webpage (no .js injection)

I have tried a few example that are out there such as extending the IResourceRequestHandler and IResponseFilter but with no luck, [IResponseFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42497464/how-can-cefsharp-intercept-xhr-request-to-obtain-response-body-value).

They are either outdated (because cefhsarp has changed a lot recently) or have pieces of information which are difficult to put together for someone who is not familiar with CefSharp.

Comment: Look at the project source for an updated IResponseFilter example.  The updated API of version 75 simplifies some aspects greatly.

Comment: I agree with that, however, when i tried to plug those in like the PassThruResponseFilter.cs, for some reason, my data was always null

Comment: Update your question to show your code.